# Azure Function Range Header for reading Blob Storage Video stream using too much data

Tags: c#, http-headers, video-streaming, azure-functions

I'm using the following code to read a Range Header from an `HttpRequestMessage` object to determine how to read a video file and send the data back (so it streams):

```
private static bool GetHttpRange(RangeItemHeaderValue rangeItemHeaderValue, long contentLength, out HttpRange httpRange)
{
    httpRange = new HttpRange();

    long actualContentLength = contentLength - 1;

    if (rangeItemHeaderValue.From != null)
    {
        httpRange.From = rangeItemHeaderValue.From.Value;

        if (rangeItemHeaderValue.To != null)
        {
            httpRange.To = rangeItemHeaderValue.To.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            httpRange.To = actualContentLength;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        httpRange.To = actualContentLength;

        if (rangeItemHeaderValue.To != null)
        {
            httpRange.From = contentLength - rangeItemHeaderValue.To.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            httpRange.From = 0;
        }
    }

    return httpRange.From < contentLength && httpRange.To < contentLength;
}
```

This streams the video perfectly! However, the requests for iPhones and Apple TVs are random and a 200MB video ends up reading 5GB of data from Blob Storage.

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using functions to stream? why not setup a [CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-create-a-storage-account-with-cdn) for your storage account

Comment: This functionality comes with AWS Lambda (it supports a Range Get method to download in chunks), surely Azure Functions has this inbuilt???